# forward stream from machine to another java

Tags: java, android, sockets, stream, wifi-direct

I am new to socket programming in java and Android. I have three phones A, B, and C. With Wifi-Direct, A can only see B. B, in the middle, can see A and C. And C can only see B. 
I want to send a file from A to C. So, A should send it to B and B will forward the data/packets to C.

I don't know where to start. should all phones use filestream? If so, how can B know if he receives data from A that he should forward it to C?

If you can show me good tutorial or small sample code this will be great.